# How to cover a condition that depends on the node env with test jest

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs

I'm currently working on an API using node and express.js. For testing and code coverage I use Jest but I have a problem: How I can cover a conditional statement that depends on the node env?

Exemple :

```
switch (config.env) {
  case "development":
    // Connect to Dev DB
    break;
  case "test":
    // Connect to Test DB
    break;
  default:
    // Connect to Prod DB
    break;
}
```

With this code when I run test coverage ( `cross-env NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/jest server/tests --coverage`), Jest answers me I cover only the 'test' case, which is normal.

Actually I have added `/* istanbul ignore next */` for not having a message telling me that I do not cover all cases.

My question is: There is a way to cover all case or it's ok to disable code coverage for this statement?

Comment: do you really want to run your tests against production DB? to get line covered you need to actually run it(and everything related will also run against prod DB)

Comment: See also https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/969.

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the `config` object manually.

`index.ts`:

```js
function connectDatabase(config) {
  switch (config.env) {
    case 'development':
      console.log('Connect to Dev DB');
      break;
    case 'test':
      console.log('Connect to Test DB');
      break;
    default:
      console.log('Connect to Prod DB');
      break;
  }
}

export { connectDatabase };
```

Unit test:

```js
import { connectDatabase } from './';

describe('test suites', () => {
  const config1 = { env: 'development' };
  const config2 = { env: 'test' };
  const config3 = { env: 'prod' };
  it.each`
    config     | name
    ${config1} | ${'Connect to Dev DB'}
    ${config2} | ${'Connect to Test DB'}
    ${config3} | ${'Connect to Prod DB'}
  `(`$name`, ({ config, name }) => {
    const consoleLogSpyOn = jest.spyOn(console, 'log');
    connectDatabase(config);
    expect(consoleLogSpyOn).toBeCalledWith(name);
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage report:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/55127764/index.spec.ts
  test suites
    ✓ Connect to Dev DB (10ms)
    ✓ Connect to Test DB (1ms)
    ✓ Connect to Prod DB (1ms)

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    Connect to Dev DB

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    Connect to Test DB

  console.log node_modules/jest-mock/build/index.js:860
    Connect to Prod DB

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.511s, estimated 4s
```

You can find completed demo here: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/55127764